# Auto: плохо или хорошо?

Tags: c++, c++11

Если везде использовать auto, это плохо или хорошо?
Конечно чем меньше низкоуровневых конструкций, тем меньше шанс ошибиться, стоит ли оно того?

Comment: что хорошего, думаю, понятно. А вот минусы вы какие видите? Разве что только увеличение времени компиляции. Хотя, не уверен, что на существенную величину

Comment: Теоретически, может несколько затруднить чтение текста и рефакторинг.

Comment: >Теоретически, может несколько затруднить чтение текста и рефакторинг

думаю, современные IDE должны решать эту проблему

Comment: @mikillskegg или наоборот. При сложных структурах данных без auto изменения надо будет вносить в большее количество мест. Даже с учётом того, что сложные структуры в c++ популярностью не пользуются (по крайней мере по сравнению с ML'ями, хаскелом и пр.), оно всё равно может стать доп. источником проблем

Comment: Лично мне код с `auto` читать сложнее.

Comment: @avp а если бы описание типа занимало строки три-четыре? Всё равно легче было бы?

Comment: Я в основном пишу на C#, в котором есть слово var (аналог auto), но, думаю, ситуация будет схожа. С какого-то момента я вообще перестал писать так: 

    Foo someFoo = new Foo();

а вместо этого пишу 

    var someFoo = new Foo()

поскольку программисту очевидно, что var здесь раскрывается в Foo.

Другое дело, если речь идет о таком коде:

    var someFoo = Another.GetSomething();

поскольку здесь уже не столь все очевидно. Так или иначе, все это дело вкуса, однако наверное очевидно, что

    std::vector<std::map<int, std::string>>::const_iterator

выглядит несколько многословно

Comment: @alexlz, что-то я не припомню описания типа длинее двух-трех слов. Тем более,  что сложные типы (вроде функции, возвращающей функцию) обычно описывают `typedef`-ом.

На самом деле проблема не в "сложных" описаниях, замаскированных `auto`, а как раз наоборот, с простыми (long, short, u_char, char \*  и т.п.).  Все-таки, когда смотришь чужой код (обычно он "не совсем правильно работает"), то приятней, когда сразу видны очевидные вещи.

Comment: @avp, использование `auto` с простыми типам надо признать признаком плохого стиля и лени. К тому же, это может быть чревато. Лучше применять ручное управление типами. Но в случае уже здесь упомянутых трехэтажных конструкций он очень удобен. Кроме того, вполне законно его применять в простых и очевидных случаях типа итеративного `for`

Comment: @mikillskegg, это понятно. 

Просто я имел в виду, что таблицы символов у компилятора очевидно реализованы лучше, чем в моей голове :)

Comment: @avp не видели потому, что это неудобно. Приведённый @DreamChild пример уже это показывает. А если этажность поболее -- устанешь расписывать. Причём наличие функций в типах необязательно. Вектор векторов, состоящих из map'ов map'ов -- уже геморрой (у меня такое на perl'е в своё время бывало, только там не вектора, а списки). Но тут уже без статической типизации с выведением типов тяжеловато. 

Ну и в качестве шутки. Ответ гугла на запрос "haskell longest type signature" -- http://i.imgur.com/Zv9JH9A.png (я уже вроде эту ссылку давал?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статья от самого евангелиста: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Answer (score 6):

В качестве ответа переведу часть [заметки Джона Скита](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=61) о комментарии Эрика Липперта по поводу аналогичной конструкции `var` в C#:

> Любой код есть абстракция. Разве код *на самом деле* манипулирует данными? Нет. Числами? Нет. Битами? Нет! Уровнями напряжения на различных пинах процессора? Нет! Электронами? Да! Но понимание кода на этом уровне — не самая лучшая мысль. Искусство кодирования — это искусство найти правильный уровень абстракции для задачи и для читателя.
>
> В высокоуровневых языках всегда есть различные стороны кода: то, *что* именно код делает, и то, *как* он это делает. Программисты, поддерживающие проект, должны понимать и то, и другое, если они хотят делать разумные изменения в коде.
>
> ...
>
> Неявная типизация локальных переменных — всего лишь один из многих путей снять акцент с того, *как* вы делаете, и тем самым акцентировать *что*. Правильно это или нет — определять вам в каждом конкретном случае. Если *вы* хотите сказать читателям вашего кода, что точный тип переменной *важен*, и его выбор критичен для последующей работы кода, не пользуйтесь неявной типизацией. Явная типизация говорит читателю: «Смотрите, это работает не просто так, обратите внимание!». Неявная типизация говорит: «В принципе, всё равно, является эта штука на самом деле `List<Customer>` или `Customer[]`,* важно лишь что это список Customer'ов».

---

*Это для C#. Аналогом для C++ было бы `Customer[]` или `std::vector<Customer>`.

Comment: Вот это отличный ответ. Хотел бы особо обратить внимание на эту часть цитаты:

    Если вы хотите сказать читателям вашего кода, что точный тип переменной важен, и его выбор критичен для последующей работы кода, не пользуйтесь неявной типизацией ....

А часто программисты просто злоупотребляют `auto`, пишут код для компилятора, а не для других людей.

Comment: @avp: Хороший код, как литературное произведение, пишется для читателя и доносит до него какую-то мысль. (В частности, читателем часто бывает сам автор — в будущем.)

Comment: Самая жесть будет если отключить контроль за типизацией вообще. А-ля void SomeMethod(dynamic parameter1, dynamic parameter2)

Comment: @SoloMio эммм..а как это соотносится  с темой вопроса? Особенно учитывая, что речь про С++, где dynamic нет (правда, есть void* но это несколько иное)

Comment: @SoloMio: `auto` в C++ _не_ означает отказа от жёсткой типизации. Вы не сможете написать

    auto x = 0.5; x = "abc";

`auto` — аналог `var`, а не `dynamic`.